# Uploading to app store through application loader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, appstore-approval, application-loader

I am uploading my app to app store through application loader,but i am not able to select the .app file as its been disabled.Should i zip the .app file before uploading??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to submit a zip file.

You will also find that with Xcode4 you can now use the built in tools for app store submission, use `Product -> Archive` and use the Submit button in the resulting organizer window.